# Stop notification timeout on hover

Tags: javascript

I have a slider error notification which slides out, displays error and disappears in 10 seconds. It can be removed earlier if you click on it.
On thing that is missing is stopping it disappearing by mouse hover.

For some people, 10 seconds is not enough to read the error.
So I need to stop the timer with mouse hover.

To summarise: I'd like it to disappear in 10 seconds as it is now if you don't interact with it. If I hover over it, the timer should be stopped and the message should stay there till you click on it to remove.

How can I stop the timer (the `setTimeout` function) on hover?

This is the message slider function:

```
function popa(text = "Internal Error!", type = "error") {
  var alert = document.createElement("div");
  var stack = document.querySelectorAll('.alert').length;
  alert.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${stack + 1}:  ${text}`));
  alert.classList.add("alert");
  alert.classList.add(`alert-${type}`);
  document.querySelector("body").appendChild(alert);
  var steps = 20;
  var width = parseInt(getComputedStyle(alert).getPropertyValue('width'));
  var slide = width + Math.round(width / 4);
  var step = Math.round(slide / steps);
  alert.onclick = () => {
    alert.parentNode.removeChild(alert);
  };
  (function next(cnt, max) {
    if (cnt++ > max) {
      return;
    }
    alert.style.right = `${(-width) + (step * cnt)}px`;
    setTimeout(() => {
      next(cnt, max);
    }, 10);
  })(0, steps);
  console.log(text);
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (alert.parentNode) {
      alert.parentNode.removeChild(alert);
    }
  }, 10000);
}
```

Thank you.

P.S. No jQuery please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.setTimeout()` returns an integer timerID which you can use with `window.clearTimeout()`:

```
var notificationTimer;

function createTimer() {
  notificationTimer = setTimeout(function(){ alert('hi'); }, 10000);
}

function clearTimer() {
  clearTimeout(notificationTimer);
}
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout